# How does the JVM guarantee execution of the finally block?

Tags: java, exception, jvm, try-catch

This question is aimed at **how the JVM is able to guarantee the execution of a finally block** (provided the JVM doesn't crash and the thread is not interrupted or exited).

Prompted by an interview question, I am trying to understand how the JVM is able to ensure a finally block is executed even in strange circumstances... Consider the following code:

```
try{

    int[] someArray = new int[10];
    int invalid = someArray[10];
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    throw new RuntimeException("Other Exception");
}
finally{

    //close open files or HTTP connections etc.
}
```

While this may be an odd circumstance, the finally block is still guaranteed to be executed despite the *Other Exception* not being explicitly handled.  How does the JVM handle situations like this?

#### My Thoughts:

From what I understand and have read so far, when an unhandled exception is encountered, control is transferred from the current thread (to that thread's `ThreadGroup` I think).  Could there be some provision in the `ThreadGroup` that checks for finally blocks that need executing?  The only other thing I can think of is perhaps the address of the finally block is stored somewhere.  Then JVM does a goto when an exception is detected and returns to the exception when the finally block has finished execution.

Can anyone clarify how this process actually happens?

Comment: I would have thought that the `finally` block would be handled before the `ThreadGroup` was notified...

Comment: An exception is not "unhandled" until it's rippled all the way up the stack and through all exception handlers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Compile this little program  (I realized I should have used your example, but it makes no difference)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Float s = Float.parseFloat("0.0327f");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I used

```
>java -version 
java version "1.8.0-ea"  // should be same for 7
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b118)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b60, mixed mode)
```

And then execute

```
javac -v -c <fully qualified class name>
```

to get the bytecode. You will see something like

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
       0: ldc           #2                  // String 0.0327f
       2: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Float.parseFloat:(Ljava/lang/String;)F
       5: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Float.valueOf:(F)Ljava/lang/Float;
       8: astore_1
       9: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      12: ldc           #6                  // String hello
      14: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      17: goto          31
      20: astore_2
      21: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      24: ldc           #6                  // String hello
      26: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      29: aload_2
      30: athrow
      31: return
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
           0     9    20   any
          20    21    20   any
    LineNumberTable:
      line 10: 0
      line 12: 9
      line 13: 17
      line 12: 20
      line 14: 31
    StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
         frame_type = 84 /* same_locals_1_stack_item */
        stack = [ class java/lang/Throwable ]
         frame_type = 10 /* same */
```

You'll notice the **code inside the `finally` appears twice**, once before the `goto` and once after. You'll also notice the `Exception table` which specifies which statement to go to if an exception occurs at some line.

So if any exception happens between statement 0-9, go to line 20 and execute the everything inside the `finally`, after the `goto`. If no exception occurs, execute the `finally` and then execute the `goto` skipping the `finally` after the `goto`.

In all cases you will have executed the code inside the `finally` block.

> Other Exception not being explicitly handled

With a `finally` block, an `Exception table` entry will be created that will handle **any** type of `Throwable`.

---

[Here's a listing of the bytecode instructions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

Comment: Ahh, so does the Exception table show what gets executed for any encountered exception?

Comment: @Joel Right. If you add a `catch(SomeException e)` to the `try-finally`, you will see an `Exception Table` entry for that exception that says where it can happen and where the execution (target) would jump to if it did.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Have a quick question for you, what if the try block has a retur statement and the finally also has a return. Java will return the value specified in finally block. Why does the try value not get returned?

Comment: @karmanaut I'm not sure how detailed an answer you want, but basically a `return` statement in a `finally` block will overwrite any value that was previously set to be returned.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I thought a return actually transfers control to the calling function? SO if the try return is executed, how does it not transfer control back and wait for finally to execute?

Comment: @karmanaut Take a look at the last paragraph [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17).

Answer (score 5):

I believe this [blog](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html) clearly describes the internal:

> If a method has defined a try-catch or a try-finally exception
> handler  then an Exception Table will be created. This contains
> information for  each exception handler or finally block including the
> range over which  the handler applies, what type of exception is being
> handled and where  the handler code is.
>
> When an exception is thrown
> the JVM looks for a matching handler in  the current method, if none
> is found the method ends abruptly popping  the current stack frame and
> the exception is re-thrown in the calling  method (the new current
> frame). If no exception handler is found  before all frames have been
> popped then the thread is terminated. This  can also cause the JVM
> itself to terminate if the exception is thrown  in the last non-daemon
> thread, for example if the thread is the main  thread.
>
> Finally exception handlers match all types of exceptions and  so
> always execute whenever an exception is thrown. In the case when no
> exception is thrown a finally block is still executed at the end of a
> method, this is achieved by jumping to the finally handler code
> immediately before the return statement is executed.

Comment: Your quote was slightly better.